# How to get list parameter into the query (like list of tags)?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I can always put list of tags in comma separated list, and parse it inside the query. But that is a little hack-ish and not elegant (I am thinking about [How to pass an array into a SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure) ).

Are there any provisions for getting list of elements for an `##Argument##`?

Comment: Don't bother - use the PostTags table and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17330137/458741, i.e. Have 5 arguments (maximum number of tags) and use the normalised table.

Comment: @ben. Thank you. I actually need two lists of tags - I wrote a query, that lists users that are active simultaneously in two tagged areas (i.e. vb6 and c++). User would supply two tag lists (e.g. [vba, vb6, excel-vba, word-vba, access-vba] and [c++ c visual-c++ visual-c++-2008]) and the query would list users that proved to be multidisciplinary in last 3 years. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/307044/query-that-returns-users-that-are-active-in-two-different-areas-specified-by-tags At the moment all parameters are hard-coded, and I want to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires some SQL magic to get this solved. I used a temporary table and stored procedure to parse two comma separated text entries. The stored procedure is recursive.

Here is the magic:

```
-- tags1: comma separated tags 
-- tags2: comma separated tags 

create table #tagselection(
  tagname varchar(35) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,
  selectiontypeid tinyint,
)

go
create procedure #split 
     @tag varchar(250)
   , @selection tinyint
AS
begin 
   declare @comma int
   declare @lhs nvarchar(50)
   print @tag
   set @tag = LTRIM(RTRIM(@tag))
   set @comma = CHARINDEX(',', @tag)
   if (@comma = 0) 
   begin
      insert into #tagselection values (@tag, @selection)
   end
   else
   begin
      set @lhs = LEFT(@tag, @comma - 1)
      insert into #tagselection values (@lhs, @selection)
      set @tag = SUBSTRING(@tag, @comma + 1, 250)
      exec #split @tag, @selection -- RECURSIVE CALL!
   end
end;

go

declare @tags1 nvarchar(250) 
declare @tags2 nvarchar(250)

set @tags1 = ##tags1:string?vb6##
set @tags2 = ##tags2:string?d,d2##


exec #split @tags1, 1;
exec #split @tags2, 2;

-- uncomment next line for debug
-- select * from #tagselection;
```

When this is run you have your tags in the temporary table `#tagselection`. I replaced the original `where Tags.TagName in ('vb6')` with

```
 where Tags.TagName in (select tagname 
                        from #tagselection 
                        where selectiontypeid = 1 )
```

and did the same for the other set of tags where selectiontypeid =2.

I forked your original query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/467462/query-that-returns-users-that-are-active-in-two-different-areas-specified-by-tags?tags1=vb6&tags2=d%2Cd2) where I implemented above solution.